# Django CheckboxSelectMultiple widget rendering as radio with Crispy Forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

The field was already set as a ModelMultipleChoiceField with the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget. It displays normally when rendering the form with `{ form.as_p }` on the template, but using CrispyForms changes the field to radio buttons.

forms.py:

```
class RequisitionModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequisitionModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['reqItems'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=Inventory.objects.all(),
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            )
```

Images:

- [Using { forms.as_p }](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PJ60.png)
- [Using { forms|crispy }](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9vd5.png)

Comment: Did you try {% crispy forms %}?

Comment: @Walucas tried it just now, doesn't seem to do anything  different from {% forms|crispy %}